# How to create stacked bar chart in ArcGIS Online dashboard?

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart by month for multiple categories. What I have found so far is to choose grouped values then go to series tab and select stacked. Unsure of next steps.

Comment: What platform are you using exactly. Is this being rendered in a map on ArcGIS Online?

Comment: in an online operations dashboard. I'd like it to look by the attached bar chart. https://resource.esriuk.com/wp-content/uploads/DashboardDark.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your category field and have it split by date.  It does not look like date fields can be used in Split by field, so if your date field is of date type, you need to do some processing in your attribute table to convert them to string, such as ("2022-05").

For resources on calculating field values, see https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/calculate-fields.htm

Answer (score 1):

> "When a serial chart is configured to use the split by option, the end
> result is a chart that has multiple categories (the categorized field)
> and multiple series (determined by the split by field). When
> displayed, the categories are displayed along the category axis and
> within each category there will be a data point for each series." -

from: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-dashboards-ideas/allow-sorting-by-statistic-in-stacked-dashboard/idi-p/1056216 -

Getting a stacked chart appears requires you to add a categories and split by field before the option for stacked will appear: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-dashboards-questions/stacked-serial-chart/td-p/92288

[Formal documentation](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000028939) is unclear regarding that point.